# Flutter Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#a2797 relayoutBoundary=up16 NEEDS-PAINT

Tags: flutter, gridview, flutter-layout

I am working on Listview converting  GridView but not showing Grid and get this error. I
also try to wrap **Expanded** in **GridView.builder**

```
 child: GridView.builder(
                  gridDelegate:
                      const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final item = catalog.items![index];
                    return Card(
         
                      child: GridTile(
                        header: Container(
                          child: Text(
                            item.name,
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                          decoration:
                              BoxDecoration(color: Colors.deepPurple),
                        ),
                        child: Image.network(item.image),
                        footer: Container(
                          child: Text(
                            item.price.toString(),
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                )
```

Comment: shrinkWrap:true

Comment: error  in a loop  **Another exception was thrown: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..7: 2991**

Comment: itemCount: catalog.items.length,

Comment: Can you include more about parent widget?

Comment: itemCount: catalog.items!.length Solved Thanks @rasityilmaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding item count length through get data

```
child: GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate:
                  const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
              ),
              itemCount: catalog.items!.length, //Adding This to Solved
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final item = catalog.items![index];
                return Card(
     
                  child: GridTile(
                    header: Container(
                      child: Text(
                        item.name,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                      decoration:
                          BoxDecoration(color: Colors.deepPurple),
                    ),
                    child: Image.network(item.image),
                    footer: Container(
                      child: Text(
                        item.price.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `shrinkWrap : true` inside `GridView.Builder`

Comment: error in a loop **Another exception was thrown: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..7: 2991**

Answer (score 0):

Try with calling `itemCount` on `GridView.builder(`

```dart
GridView.builder(
  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
  ),
  itemCount: item.length, //this
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
```

Also have the `Expanaded` widget if it inside `Colum` widget.